# Azure AD administration scripting with .NET

Tags: .net, powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

There is a way to automate administrative tasks in Azure AD by using the [AzureAD PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) (eg. querying users, assigning them to applications, registering applications etc.).

Is there a way to automate such tasks from .NET?

Comment: yeah, do http requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) to perform operations such as querying users, assigning them to applications, registering applications etc .

To call Microsoft Graph, your app must acquire an access token from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).The access token contains information (or claims) about your app and the permissions it has for the resources and APIs available through Microsoft Graph. To get an access token, your app must be able to authenticate with Azure AD and be authorized by either a user or an administrator for access to the Microsoft Graph resources it needs.Please refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) for more details.

After acquiring token , you could make graph api calls .For example ,list users api operarion :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

Microsoft publishes open source client libraries and server middleware for both the Azure AD and Azure AD v2.0 endpoints.For the Azure AD endpoint , you can use 
[Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) . For the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint,you could use [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries) .